# Angular template not displaying data generatd by a method called from another component

Tags: angular, templates, components, display

I have two components ComponentA and ComponentB

COMPONENT A .ts CODE

```
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
 name: string;
 constructor() {}
 
 showName(){ 
    this.name = "Timothy";
    console.log('inside showName' + this.name);
 }
}
```

COMPONENT A .html CODE

```
 <button (click)="showName()">Click to see the name</button>    <div *ngIf="name?.length>0">{{name}}</div>
```

When I click on the componentA template button I do see the console and the name in the browser.

```
export class ComponentB extends ComponentA  implements OnInit {
  constructor() { 
   super();
 }
```

}

COMPONENT B.html CODE

```
<button (click)="showName();">Show The Name</button>
```

But when I click on componentB button, I can see the console.log data, but the name does not appear on the browser. Can anyone tell me what I've not done

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are not binding `name` in `ComponentB`. With the inheritance from `ComponentA`, you only get the functionality implemented in component's class, not the template.

In your `ComponentB` template, you have to do the following:

```
<button (click)="showName();">Show The Name</button>
<div *ngIf="name?.length>0">{{name}}</div>
```

Check this [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qyesax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild-component%2Fchild-component.component.html) as an example, where I have inherited `AppComponent` in `ChildComponent`

Comment: I want the name to show in ComponentA template when ComponentB button is clicked. I don't want to show the name in ComponentB template